# How can I change the name of application.css in a rails project?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I'd like to change the name of the file of application.css but this yields the following error:

`Asset filtered out and will not be served`

I'm assuming this is because somewhere in the config files, rails is told to precompile `application.css`, and when I change its name, the config file still looks for `application.css`. can someone explain to me how I would go about doing this?

I ask because I would like to learn how to create my own manifest files for different controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried include your new .css file to the list: config.assets.precompile += %w( newname.css ) in 'config/environtment/production.rb'?

The joke is in that you probably on the last rails 4 version. The rails team included sprockets_better_errors gem into out of the box functionality, so it checks 'precompilability' of assets even in development mode. Prior to that, you would not see any error, until deployment to the production

Hope it helps